# Is it possible to create a jar for test classes that contains the test dependencies using maven?

Tags: java, maven, testing, jar

I've managed to create a jar containing the class files with dependencies and a separate jar containing the test classes for a java system. I'm trying to execute the test classes from the command line using JUnit, like so:

`java -cp <test-classes-jar>:<junit-jar>:<hamcrest-jar> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass`

However, the test cases won't execute due to the tests using google truth, resulting in a class not found error. I know I can work around this by appending the google truth jar onto the class path, but I'd like to avoid this.

Is there a way to generate a single jar which contains the test classes and their dependencies?

Comment: I don't think so. Could you please explain why you want to create such a jar? Which problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to apply an external tool to trace the execution of the test cases. This requires me to execute the test cases from the command line, which in turn requires the dependencies for the test cases to be on the class path. If a system has a test class with many dependencies, I'd have to manually add each to the class path. It'd be much easier if I could produce a single jar that contained them all.

Comment: It is best to run the tests during the Maven build. You can probably use the output and the reports to gather the information you need.